# How to run Java code in in JMeter and pass vairables from java code to Jmeter script

Tags: jmeter

I am reading xlsx file by adding Beanshell Preprocessor. When i run code in Eclispe, it's working fine.

But when i run in Jmeter, i am getting below error. I have copied required jar files in Jmeter lib and lib\ext as well.

> 2015/06/08 14:53:04 ERROR - jmeter.util.BeanShellInterpreter: Error
>   invoking bsh method: eval
>
> In file: inline evaluation of:       import java.io.File; import
>   java.io.FileInputStream;       import java.io.IOException; . . . ''
>   Encountered "=" at line 18, column 41.    2015/06/08 14:53:04 WARN  -
>   jmeter.modifiers.BeanShellPreProcessor: Problem in BeanShell script
>   org.apache.jorphan.util.JMeterException: Error invoking bsh   method:
>   eval  In file: inline evaluation of: ``import java.io.File; import
>   java.io.FileInputStream; import java.io.IOException; . . . ''
>   Encountered "=" at   line 18, column 41."

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Iterator;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

public class url {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        FileInputStream file=new FileInputStream(new File("C:\\temp\\project.xlsx"));

        XSSFWorkbook workbook=new XSSFWorkbook(file);
        XSSFSheet sheet=workbook.getSheetAt(0);
        Iterator<Row>rowIterator=sheet.iterator();

        int count=1;
        while(rowIterator.hasNext()){
            Row row=rowIterator.next();
            Iterator<Cell> cellIterator=row.cellIterator();
            while(cellIterator.hasNext()){
                Cell cell=cellIterator.next();
                String TextInCell=cell.toString();
                String cellContent1="Cricket";
                String cellContent2="Football";
                String cellContent3="F1";
                String cellContent4="Badminton";
                String cellContent5="Misslenous";

                if(TextInCell.contains(cellContent1)){
                    String var=cell.getRichStringCellValue().toString();
                    String Category = cellContent1;

                }else if(TextInCell.contains(cellContent2)){
                    String var=cell.getRichStringCellValue().toString();
                    String Category = cellContent2;

                }else if(TextInCell.contains(cellContent3)){
                    String var=cell.getRichStringCellValue().toString();
                    String Category = cellContent3;

                }else if(TextInCell.contains(cellContent4)){

                    String var=cell.getRichStringCellValue().toString();
                    String Category = cellContent4;
                    System.out.println(var + "----"+Category );

                }else{
                    String var=cell.getRichStringCellValue().toString();
                    String Category = cellContent5;

                }

            }

        }

    }


}
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Beanshell is not very Java, you need to amend your code to match Beanshell conventions to wit:

   - remove "class" and "main" method
   - remove `<Cell>` from `Iterator<Cell>`
   - remove `<Row>` from `Iterator<Row>`
   - explicitly cast Objects like `Row row=(Row)rowIterator.next();`
2. Beanshell has well-known performance problems, if you need to deal with Excel files I would recommend going for [JSR223 PreProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor) and "groovy" language instead. To enable "groovy" support just [download groovy-all.jar](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.groovy/groovy-all) and drop it to the /lib folder of your JMeter installation
3. JMeter restart is required to pick up groovy or POI or whatever jars.
4. See [How to Extract Data From Files With JMeter](https://blazemeter.com/blog/what-every-performance-tester-should-know-about-extracting-data-files-jmeter) guide for more information on dealing with binary files, hopefully you'll get some clues.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I made some changes in my code. Removed "class" and "main" method. Insted of xlsx as input i am passing txt file now. Eveyrthing works in Beanshell.